# Webcasting and ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, connection, streaming, upload

I am having lots of issues streaming live on the web and being able to have high quality video without wifi delays, dropouts or just plain horrible connection/upload speeds.

The option to get would be ethernet to greatly improve connectivity and upload speeds.

My question is really probably a clarification of what I've seen on the web. Can I run an ethernet connection upwards of anywhere up to 300' and be able to utilize the full strength of the connection without dropoff in signal strength, thus keeping me connected without the dropout of wifi - or possible data throttling by the carriers?

Thanks.

Comment: An ethernet cable won't improve your upload speed, it is a physical medium, its throughput will be the same regardless of the direction of the flow of data - also, cable length doesn't have anything to do with carriers throttling your speed. I think many concepts are being misunderstood in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Can I run an ethernet connection upwards of anywhere up to 300'

Yes.

> When used for 10/100/1000BASE-T, the maximum allowed length of a Cat 6 cable is up to 100 meters (328 ft). This consists of 90 meters (295 ft) of solid "horizontal" cabling between the patch panel and the wall jack, plus 5 meters (16 ft) of stranded patch cable between each jack and the attached device. For 10GBASE-T, an unshielded Cat 6 cable should not exceed 55 metres.

Source [Category 6 cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable#Maximum_length)

Note:

- Replacing a Wireless connection with an Ethernet Connection won't improve a bad internet connection or get around any ISP throttling.

Comment: I think the answer isn't complete without mentioning that ethernet won't improve the situation if the culprit is a bad internet connection, or throttling by the ISP.

Comment: @dirkt Good point. Added.